# Binding Shape and Size of Node to Clipping Mask in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Is there a convenient way for a clipping mask to just bind whatever shape/size the target node has? Consider the following Region node:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Region content = new Region();
        content.setStyle(
            "-fx-background-color: #444444;" +
            "-fx-background-radius: 50px;" +
            "-fx-max-width: 150px;" +
            "-fx-max-height: 150px;");
        StackPane root = new StackPane(content);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

How can I have a mask that can automatically adjust its own shape and size accordingly?

---

#### EDIT

This is how I implement this stuff, but it's too long and inconvenient:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Region content1 = new Region();
        content1.setStyle(
            "-fx-background-color: teal;" +
            "-fx-background-radius: 50px;" +
            "-fx-pref-width: 150px;" +
            "-fx-pref-height: 150px;" +
            "-fx-translate-x: 30px;" +
            "-fx-translate-y: 30px;");

        Rectangle mask = new Rectangle();

        Region content2 = new Region() {{
            // TODO: Implement better clip mask size and shape handling
            mask.widthProperty().bind(widthProperty());
            mask.heightProperty().bind(heightProperty());
            backgroundProperty().addListener(((observable, oldBackground, newBackground) -> {
                for (BackgroundFill backgroundFill : newBackground.getFills()) {
                    double topLeftHRadius = backgroundFill.getRadii().getTopLeftHorizontalRadius();
                    double topLeftVRadius = backgroundFill.getRadii().getTopLeftVerticalRadius();
                    double topRightHRadius = backgroundFill.getRadii().getTopRightHorizontalRadius();
                    double topRightVRadius = backgroundFill.getRadii().getTopRightVerticalRadius();
                    double bottomLeftHRadius = backgroundFill.getRadii().getBottomLeftHorizontalRadius();
                    double bottomLeftVRadius = backgroundFill.getRadii().getBottomLeftVerticalRadius();
                    double bottomRightHRadius = backgroundFill.getRadii().getBottomRightHorizontalRadius();
                    double bottomRightVRadius = backgroundFill.getRadii().getBottomRightVerticalRadius();
                    mask.setArcWidth((topLeftHRadius + topRightHRadius + bottomLeftHRadius + bottomRightHRadius) / 2);
                    mask.setArcHeight((topLeftVRadius + topRightVRadius + bottomLeftVRadius + bottomRightVRadius) / 2);
                }
            }));
            setClip(mask);
            getChildren().add(content1);
        }};
        content2.setStyle(
            "-fx-background-color: cyan;" +
            "-fx-background-radius: 50px;" +
            "-fx-pref-width: 150px;" +
            "-fx-pref-height: 150px;" +
            "-fx-translate-x: 70px;" +
            "-fx-translate-y: 70px;");

        Region root = new Region() {{
            getChildren().add(content2);
        }};

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a convenient, and better way to do this. On the other hand, the HTML + CSS [overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp) property can easily achieve this:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background-color: cyan;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  /* clipping property */
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  background-color: teal;
  border-radius: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: What is the point of a clip which is the same shape and size of the node being clipped?  I don't think it would achieve anything at all.

Comment: @jewelsea I mean to simply clip the content, or something like [overflowing](https://news.kynosarges.org/2016/11/03/javafx-pane-clipping) clip. In HTML + CSS, this can be easily achieved using [`overflow`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp) property.

Answer (score 1):

Run the code and try to manipulate the size of the window.

```java
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class ClipApp extends Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView("https://hips.hearstapps.com/ghk.h-cdn.co/assets/18/01/2048x1024/landscape-1515004324-boston-terrier.jpg?resize=480:*");
            StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(imageView);
            Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();

            Circle circle = new Circle(60);
            circle.centerXProperty().bind(stackPane.widthProperty().divide(2.));
            circle.centerYProperty().bind(stackPane.heightProperty().divide(2.));
            stackPane.setClip(circle);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Binding properties are the way to go. But what if I want the Shape node to be the exact same size and shape as the target Node? Like from my example Region node, it'll probably much easier to just clone the node itself and set the other one as its clipping mask?

Comment: I would rather use Rectangle instead of cloned Region. But the whole concept you presented is correct.

Comment: Yes, for some reasons, if any node is set as mask except for Shape nodes, the entire node is not rendered at all. Right now I'm trying a different approach other than clipping mask to achieve the same effect. Will update my post later...

Comment: "it'll probably much easier to just clone the node itself" => JavaFX doesn't natively support cloning of nodes, so that could be difficult to achieve.

Comment: @jewelsea Sorry for my choice of words, but I mean two instance of same node and set the other one as the clip mask of the other